# Song count is not syncing with iTunes

Tags: sync, itunes, itunes-11

I noticed recently that the song counts in iTunes weren't increasing (despite me listening to them quite a bit on my iPhone). I had switched to wireless syncing within the last couple months, so I wondered if that might be the cause. Though I had upgraded to iTunes 11 within the last couple months as well (and I'm not sure exactly how long this has been going on).

If I wirelessly sync, and then sync with a USB cord, the song count won't update, but if I only sync using a USB cord, the song count increments. This makes me think that the phone *thinks* it's syncing the play counts when wirelessly syncing.

- Play song -> Wirelessly sync -> Song count **does not** update
- Play song -> Wirelessly sync -> Sync with a cord -> Song count **does
  not** update
- Play song -> Sync with a cord - > Song count **does** update

Is there any planned correction of this issue (I couldn't find anything)? Or is there a work around/setting/etc. that would fix the issue? Or is this only happening to me (may have a corrupt file somewhere)?

Comment: Do you use iCloud ?

Comment: I do, yes. [Space filler]

Comment: According to [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3396986?start=45&tstart=0) iCloud can cause these problems. Read this long thread and especially the last page and see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just you. It seems to have been a bug.
It's fixed in the latest 11.0.2 iTunes update IIRC.

Short songs (under ~25 seconds) still seem to have this bug though

Comment: I have the most recent version of iTunes (11.0.2) and the issue is still present. Do you happen to have a link to the discussion/bug ticket/release notes you're referencing?